# Add an ad code as a variable inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the html ad code to insert into one of my websites. But the script on my website uses a config file and the ad code should be defined in it. I have tried using many techniques of adding the ad code in it but everything failed. Below is the code I have in my script's config file:

```
$config = array(
    // Your Site URL
    "url" => "http://www.example.com",
    // Your Site Title
    "title" => "Example.com",
    // Your Site Description
    "description" => "Description goes here",
    // Google Analytics ID
    "ga" => "",
    // Ad Codes
    "ad728" => "",
    "ad468" => "",
    "ad300" => "",
);
```

My question is, how to include the ad code inside these values. I have tried writing a separate html file with the ad code inside it and tried including it in this variable but nothing seems to work. The output is a plain text on the homepage.

Comment: So you need to insert html into this array after the fact that the array has already been defined?

Comment: Yes, I suppose the script works that way, that's why this config file has the undefined variables in it for ad code. If I could only understand how to make this work.

Comment: So why can't you just write the html inside the `"ad728" => "<script>stuff</script>"` quotes in this config array?

Comment: The ad code I am trying to use contains two <script> tags in it. The script starts throwing this error:

` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'text' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in /home/vhosts/example.mn/example.com/includes/Config.php on line 17 `

Comment: I tried one more thing with it. I created another file named ad728.html and placed the whole ad code inside it and then included this file in the script tag with src attribute like this:  <script src="ad728.html"></script>

But it gave the same unexpected 'text (T_STRING) error on this as well.

Comment: That's likely because you need to escape your quotes in your script code if you are using the same kind of quotes to wrap your html in. So like this: `"adcode" => "use backslashes to \"escape\" your quotes"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

1) Just `escape` your code (use backslashes on conflicting quotes):

```
// This is probably the easiest thing to do (provided your script isn't massive).
$config['ad300']  =  '<script>MyJavascript(\'AddCodeValue\')</script>';
```

2) Alternate concatenation. It's ugly but works! You always have to use double quotes where you use single quotes and vice versa.

```
// Notice the double quotes wrapping single quotes here
$config['ad300']  =  '<script>MyJavascript('."'AddCodeValue'".')</script>';
```

3) Use the `HEREDOC` markup and assign the variable in array.

```
$add1  =  <<<EOF
          <script>MyJavascript('AddCodeValue')</script>
EOF;

$config['ad300']  =  $add1;
```

4) Use output buffer with an included file or echoed text.

```
    ob_start();
    // Everything between start and end_clean
    // whether it be include, code, whatever,
    // will be saved into a cache essentially
    include('ad728.php'); ?>
<script>
    $('#myadd1').do(function() {
        $("#add1_container").html("stuff");
    });
</script>
    <?php
    // Once you are done with your code, you
    // just save the contents of the cache (buffer)
    // to a varaible
    $add1  =  ob_get_contents();
    // This stops the buffer from caching
    // and clears it out
    ob_end_clean();

// Assign the variable to the array
$config['ad300']  =  $add1;
```

Comment: Your heredoc is not closed properly though. The EOF; should be placed w/out any space

Comment: @DarkBee Thanks for the note, I have never used `HEREDOC` (and it shows I guess!). I will revise.